# I want to know what happens when *this is returned

Tags: c++, pointers, return, operators, this

Let's say you have

```
class Something
{
    int nVal1;
public:
    Something(int x = 0) { nVal1 = x }
    Something& operator++()
    {
        if (nVal1 == 9)
            nVal1 = 0;
        else
            ++nVal1;

        return *this; 
    }
};

int main()
{
    Something test3;
    ++test3;
}
```

I am still new to C++ so correct me if I am wrong. The `this` pointer returns the reference to the object that invokes the overloaded `operator++`. `++nVal1` is local to the member function, but because it is a member function that operates on the state of the `test3` object the value of `nVal1` doesn't change unless its reassigned or the object is destroyed? Also, when `*this` is returned does is it returning the changes to the object? Like here is the

```
Something object(test3 address)
```

with the changes to its state? I understand that Classes allow you to create your own data types and store data. I think the my biggest confusion is what is the function returning and where is it sending it. Does it sort of overwrite the previous state of that object?

Answer (score 0):

> but because it is a member function that operates on the state of the test3 object the value of nVal1 doesn't change unless its reassigned or the object is destroyed?

The value of `nVal1` will change when you call `operator++()` on `Something`. The fact that you are also returning the new value has nothing to do with the change that you are performing to `nVal1`.

The semantics of `operator++()`, on a generic object `i`, simply requires that you return the new value, so that the behaviour in, for example:

```
std::cout << (++i);
```

is defined.

But even if you simply call it and ignore the result, like in your `main`, the value will still be changed.

Answer (score 0):

As written, the code will change `test3.nVal1` when `operator++()` is called - I'm not sure why you think it would not. The returning of `*this` is a pattern used for some operators to allow chaining; e.g. `++(++test3)`, or to allow the results of the increment to be, for example, passed to another function, such as being assigned to another `Something`; e.g.

```
Something test4 = ++test3;
```

Comment: Except that `operator++(int)` should return by value, so in your example: `(test3++)++` would actually increment `test3` only once. And also OP is defining `operator++()` not `operator++(int)`.

Comment: Duh - typing faster than I'm thinking. Fixed.